# What's Automapper for?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, automapper

What’s [Automapper](http://www.codeplex.com/AutoMapper) for?

How will it help me with my domain and controller layers (asp.net mvc)?

Comment: Possible duplicate/related question (but includes a good example) is <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036341/help-me-understand-automapper>

Comment: Here is a good explaination:  http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2013/01/what-is-automapper-and-how-to-map-objects.html

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Maybe an example will help here...

Let's say you have a nicely-normalized database schema like this:

```
Orders       (OrderID, CustomerID, OrderDate)  
Customers    (CustomerID, Name)  
OrderDetails (OrderDetID, OrderID, ProductID, Qty)  
Products     (ProductID, ProductName, UnitPrice)
```

And let's say you're using a nice O/R mapper that hands you back a well-organized domain model:

```
OrderDetail
+--ID
+--Order
|--+--Date
|--+--Customer
|-----+--ID
|-----+--Name
+--Product
|--+--ID
|--+--Name
|--+--UnitPrice
+--Qty
```

Now you're given a requirement to display everything that's been ordered in the last month.  You want to bind this to a flat grid, so you dutifully write a flat class to bind:

```
public class OrderDetailDto
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public int OrderCustomerID { get; set; }
    public string OrderCustomerName { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public Decimal ProductUnitPrice { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }

    public Decimal TotalPrice
    {
        get { return ProductUnitPrice * Qty; }
    }
}
```

That was pretty painless so far, but what now?  How do we turn a bunch of `OrderDetail`s into a bunch of `OrderDetailDto`s for data binding?

You might put a constructor on `OrderDto` that takes an `OrderDetail`, and write a big mess of mapping code.  Or you might have a static conversion class somewhere.  Or, you could use AutoMapper, and write this instead:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<OrderDetail, OrderDetailDto>();
OrderDetailDto[] items =
    Mapper.Map<OrderDetail[], OrderDetailDto[]>(orderDetails);
GridView1.DataSource = items;
```

There.  We've just taken what would otherwise have been a disgusting mess of pointless mapping code and reduced it into three lines (really just two for the actual mapping).

Does that help explain the purpose?

Comment: Nearly everything. If u add more about the power of Automapper, I am sure people will upvote...

Answer (score 3):

If you have an object of one type and you want to populate the properties of an object of another type using properties from the first type, you have two choices:

1. Manually write code to do such a mapping.
2. Use a tool that will automatically handle this for you.

AutoMapper is an example of 2.

The most common use is to flatten models into a data transfer objects (or, in general, mapping across layer boundaries). What's very nice about AutoMapper is that for common scenarios you don't have to do any configuring ([convention over configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration)).

Answer (score 0):

Map objects between layers. Good example: [Here](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/10/08/an-automapper-success-story.aspx)